# Integration between Project Web Access and SharePoint (Gantt Charts)

Tags: sharepoint, integration, gantt-chart, project-web-access

I'm a newbie to using Project Web Access and I wondered if someone can guide me by giving links that help in integration of SharePoint site with Project Web Access.

What I want to do is to generate Gantt charts inside a regular SharePoint site. I know that there is a standard view to generate charts in SharePoint but I need the more customizable view in Project Web Access.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the Project Details web part into the project workspace. That will allow you to use its Gantt Chart view.